# Load login shell inside user cronjob

Tags: shell, crontab, rvm, interactive

I'm trying to run a rake task using a scheduled cronjob. My crontab looks something like this:

```
0 1 * * 1-7 /bin/bash -l -c "cd ~/jobs/rake && rake reports:create >> ~/jobs/logs/cron.log"
```

Ruby on my account is provided by RVM, which is loaded via `~/.bashrc` (before the no-interaction check):

```
# load RVM env
[[ -s $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] && source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# ... rest of logic
```

Time and again, this task fails to run since RVM isn't loaded when the task is called (uses system's `/usr/bin/ruby` instead), and gem dependencies are missing.

How can I make crontab load my shell environment before executing my scheduled jobs? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little digging following the response from @mpapis, it seems there's a page on the RVM site which [elaborates how to use a specific RVM install in a script executed by cron](https://rvm.io/integration/cron/).

Basically you find out which RVM you'd like to use by running this (using ruby 1.9.3 here):

```
$ rvm env --path -- 1.9.3-p125
```

Substitute your specific ruby version. This will point to the file that needs to be `source`ed  so that your desired ruby environment is loaded.

Write the script to be run by your cron job:

### myjob.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# the full path to the RVM env you got from running `rvm env ...`
source ~/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.3-p125

# do stuff ...
cd ~/jobs/rake
rake reports:create
```

Make sure you make the file executable:

```
chmod u+x myjob.sh
```

### crontab

```
0 1 * * 1-7 bash -c "cd ~/jobs && ./myjob.sh"
```

#### BAM! Done.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't simply sourcing your ~/.bashrc in the cronjob work?

```
0 1 * * 1-7 /bin/bash -l -c "source ~/.bashrc; cd ~/jobs/rake && rake reports:create >> ~/jobs/logs/cron.log"
```

Comment: I thought so too, but that didn't work.

Comment: @sa125 Could that be because of the `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return` line? I'm pretty sure cronjobs don't run in an interactive shell. Alternatively, could you not put `[[ -s $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] && source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm` into the cron line?

Comment: First - I appreciate your help. I tried moving the `[[ -s $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] && source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm` line into it's own file, `~/.loadrvm`. I then modified the crontab line to `0 1 * * 1-7 /bin/bash -l -c "source ~/.loadrvm && echo \`which ruby\` >> ~/cron.log"`. I still get `/usr/bin/ruby`.

Comment: @sa125 Could this be because you are starting bash as a login shell (-l) instead of an interactive shell?

Answer (score 2):

using login shell is not recommended in background processes.

you can use this method:

```
0 1 * * 1-7 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm in ~/jobs/rake do rake reports:create >> ~/jobs/logs/cron.log"
```

also there is `rvm cron` command:

```
rvm help cron
```